# i want to create two tabs with same style but the js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am using a plugin (modal window) which can create modal.

On the same page, I have two different w3-card (I might need more in the future with the same layout) which I use the modal to open them.

On each modal I have 3 tabs. I copied them from w3school this is the link https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_tabulators_active.

But the tabs only work for one of the card. I changed the id name on one card along with the function names in js section but still doesn't work.

What should I do?
Thanks in advance,

(edit)

```
<!-- card No.1--> 
<span class="wow-modal-id-1"> <!-- the code that the plugin gives-->
 <div class="w3-card-4">
  <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
</span>

<!-- card No.2-->
<span class="wow-modal-id-2">
 <div class="w3-card-4">
  <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
</span>
```

then I want in the modal there will be the tabs  which i shared the link (just because it is too much i didn't paste them here.)

Comment: Can you please provide your Javascript code that controls the tabs? You may have forgotten the HTML part for the tabs too..

Comment: OP should also include the CSS used for this: [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Use below code without JS

```css
main {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.main-tab section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #abc;
}

.main-tab input {
  display: none;
}

.main-tab label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #abc;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.main-tab label:before {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


.main-tab label:hover {
  color: #789;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-tab input:checked + label {
  color: #0af;
  border: 1px solid #abc;
  border-top: 2px solid #0af;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-tab">
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
  <section id="content1">
    <p>
      Test tab 1
    </p>
  </section>
  <section id="content2">
    <p>
      Test tab 2
    </p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Well, it stopped working,
The tabs in another card can't open.
I changed the id names, but...